# Sync data between MicroService and Monolithic sytem

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, etl

I have a giant monolithic which has around a million entities. I want to sync data to the micro-service so that it always has the same replica of entities with some fields as the monolithic system. There are 2 ways to do so:

- Write an API for the microservice and fetch data through rest calls in
  batches
- Write an ETL service that directly connect to database of
  monolithic and the database of microservice to load the data.

The drawback of the first approach is that it will include a number of Rest calls and would be slow as I could be having a million of records. The second approach breaks the microservices principle(Correct me if it is not the principal) as apart from microservice ETL service would be accessing the database.

Note:I only want to sync some fields from the record not all say if a record has 200 fields  and in my service only 2 fields are being used, then I need to have all records with only those 3 fields.And number of records being used can be changed dynamically.Say after some times the service is using 4 fields than 3,then i need to bring that 4th field into the db of my microservice.

So can anyone suggest which approach is better?

Answer (score 2):

The first approach is better in terms of low-coupling high-cohesion since you have a clear interface (the REST api) between what you expose from the monolith and the data inside the monolith. In the long run, it makes both the microservice and the monolith easier to maintain.

But there's a third approach that's especially suitable for data synchronisation: asynchronous integration. Basically you monolith would need to send out a stream of change data messages, e.g. to a message queue or something like kafka. These messages are the interface, so you get the same advantage of low-coupling as with the REST API. But you also get additional advantages.

- You don't have the overhead of REST calls, just an asynchronous message listener.
- If the monolith is down or slow responding, you microservice is not affected.

There is a problem however of bootstrapping: do you retro-actively need to generate events for everything that happened in the past, or can you start from some point in time and keep everything in sync from that point onwards?

Comment: I want the events that happened in past as well

Answer (score 1):

What is your end goal here -

1. Is it to slowly migrate from Monolithic to Micro-services by distributing traffic between two systems. 
   or
2. On a fine day, completely cutover to new Micro-services.

If its second approach, I would do ETL for data migration.

If its First approach -

- Implement an CDC/or just changes in monolithic service to publish the persistent operations to Messaging system (Kafka.Rabbit).
- Implement the subscriber on Micro-services and update the DB.
- Once confident on Pub/Sub implementation, redirect all reads to micro-services system.
- Then slowly divert some percentage of persistent calls to micro-services which will do a rest call to old system to update old DB.
- Once you are confide on new services and data quality and other requirements(performance), completely  cutover to new Micro-services).

** you need to do historic sync before starting the Async Messaging process.

This is one way to smoothly cutover from old systems.

Comment: To slowly migrate over microservices

Comment: ok.. you can implement the steps mentioned above. There might be few tweaks necessary as there is no single solution. It all depends upon the project, data limitations and more.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to synchronise data between monolithic and microservice? 
Are you rewriting monolithic to MicroService? If this is the case, I would prefer using ETL service for data synchronisation as this is more standardised for data synchronisation compared to rest calls.